# Chrome "Unloading" Images?

Tags: php, google-chrome, resize

I am writing a PHP script to dynamically resize an image. The image ID (from a MySQL db) is passed in like this : "http://localhost/getimage/1.htm".

When I go directly to the scrippt with a URL like above, the image is spat out perfectly. But for some reason (only in Chrome), when I link that URL to an  tag it starts acting weird. When the page first loads the image loads fine, but then the loading bar spins for about 5 seconds and suddenly the image disappears and Chrome shows a "Failed to load resource" error.

Does anyone have any idea what might be causing this and, if so, how to stop it? I thought that it might have had something to do with AdBlocker, but I have disabled that and it is stil happening.

Cheers.

Edit: This is the code that I am using:

```
    header('Content-Type:'.$file['type']);
    header('Content-Length: ' . $file['bytes']);

    // Get size of original image
    list($o_width, $o_height) = getimagesize($file['src']);

    // Default width and height
    if (is_null($width)) {
        $width = $o_width;
    }

    if (is_null($height)) {
        $height = $width;
    }

    // Create image frame
    $image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);

    // Generate image depending on source type
    switch ($file['type']) {
        case "image/jpeg":
        default:
            $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($file['src']);
            break;
        case "image/gif":
            $image = imagecreatefromgif($file['src']);
            break;
        case "image/png":
            $image = imagecreatefrompng($file['src']);
            break;
    }

    imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $o_width, $o_height);

    // Output
    imagejpeg($image_p, null, 100);
    exit;
```

As you can see I am setting the content types. If it was the htm extension, confusing it, would that explain why the image loads correctly, and then unloads itself?

Comment: Do you have a demo or code to show us?

Comment: Make sure you're serving the image with the correct content-type. The htm extension may be confusing the browser.

Comment: My first guess would be something to do with the Cache.. It might be loading the version in Cache, noticing it's different, trying to load it from the url, and getting a .htm page? But then again, I can't even tell HOW you're linking to the image, or what tag, so I can't make any good guesses.

Comment: did you investigate in Chrome Inspector's Network tab + in the webserver's log? Maybe you'll see something strange there

Comment: Added the code I am using to the original post.

Nothing showing up in the network tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is not Chrome only, but IMHO it is wrong that you have this at the beginning: header('Content-Length: ' . $file['bytes']); because you don't know the actual file size, since you create the image on the fly with imagejpeg($image_p, null, 100); Try commenting out the header('Content-Length... line, it might fix it.